# injection of empty set from reading properties

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, collections, spring-el

```
<property name="listOfIds" value="#{'${list.ids}'.trim().split(' *, *')}"/>
```

I am setting a list of Ids with `spring` bean and I was wondering if there was a way of initialising my collection `Set` to be `empty` with `SPEL` if no properties were set:

```
list.ids=
```

such that when I call...

```
 if (connection.getListOfIds().isEmpty()) {
    //do something
    }
```

it returns that the set contains no elements. or Is there an alternative way I can read in empty set from the properties file.

Comment: "#primes?:T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()"

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use Elvis operator **?:** and return **T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()**

**"#primes?:T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()"**

Default values can be provided as ${myProps.item:#{defaultValue}}

Comment: how should  I write this with `<property name="listOfIds" value="#{'${list.ids}'.trim().split(' *, *')}"/>` so that it returns empty only if ids is empty

Comment: can you replace list.ids by list.ids:""  (or) list.ids:#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}